# Decompile an App getting confused RC2 Files

Tags: java, c++, xml

I was decompile an App from a Friend and getting the Sourcecode.
I have now the Java files and the XML Files. The thing is: If i open the RC2 Files at visual studio or some other Editor i see only confused symbols. Why is that? Is this  a protection that you cant get the full source out of the app or i make something wrong?
I was decompile with dex2jar, apk tool, jd-gui. 
The App was 390mb. So its a little big App. Or i should try any other options to see the full sourcecode? And the other Question is: can i full modify the app and recompile it? I only want to modify little things like. And its a game btw.
Ty for the Answers

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That will help other members to understand your 

problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi ty for the Links. I can only upload one of the files to understand. https://ufile.io/2hgtk here if this is legal to write such Links.

Comment: [RC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2) is a block cypher.  Probably those files are encrypted, and hence unreadable.  If so then you will need to decrypt them before you can read them.

Comment: yeah that was also in my mind. but how i see which decryption i need? looks really confused.

Comment: Or only the "creator" can decrypt? I was read about a privatekey to decrypt. Can a "Third user" decrypt it? Its then cracking the files? and how? I really want to understand how someone can decrypt the file than.